# Iterate through ee.List of strings containing dates to subset to new ImageCollection

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, filter, subset

I've got a Sentinel-2 `ImageCollection` that I want to subset by date. The example below contains images from two dates (2019-02-17 & 2019-02-20), and I want to separate them. The `i_date` and `f_date` variables are obtained from an external timestamp, +/- 3 days. Once separated, I want to calculate some scores on the resulting `ImageCollections` after clipping with the polygon and then select the date with the highest score.

How do I iterate over the `ymd_ee` server-side list to subset the ImageCollection into a new one with only those dates? I want to avoid the `.getInfo()` operator as much as possible.

```
import ee
ee.Initialize()
s2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
s2_cloud_probability = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_CLOUD_PROBABILITY')

def ymdEEList(imgcol):
    def iter_func(image, newlist):
        date = ee.Number.parse(image.date().format("YYYYMMdd"))
        newlist = ee.List(newlist)
        return ee.List(newlist.add(date).sort())
    ymd = imgcol.iterate(iter_func, ee.List([]))
    return ee.List(ee.Dictionary(ee.List(ymd).reduce(ee.Reducer.frequencyHistogram())).keys())

polygon = ee.Geometry.Polygon([-122.2,48.5,-122.3,48.5,-122.3,49.5,-122.2,49.5,-122.2,48.5])
CLOUD_FILTER = 60

#A lot of this was derived from this tutorial: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorials/community/sentinel-2-s2cloudless
i_date = '2019-02-16'
f_date = '2019-02-22'
s2_date_region = s2.filterDate(i_date,f_date).filterBounds(polygon)
s2_cloud_probability_date_region = s2_cloud_probability.filterDate(i_date,f_date).filterBounds(polygon)
s2_merged_date_region = ee.ImageCollection(ee.Join.saveFirst('s2cloudless').apply(**{
    'primary':s2_date_region.filter(ee.Filter.lte('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', CLOUD_FILTER)),
    'secondary':s2_cloud_probability_date_region,
    'condition':ee.Filter.equals(**{
        'leftField':'system:index',
        'rightField':'system:index'
    })
}))

ymd_ee = ymdEEList(s2_merged_date_region) #this is an ee.List()
#ymd_ee.getInfo() gives ['20190217', '20190220'] but want to avoid getInfo()
#Want to iterate over this ymd_ee list and subset the ImageCollection to only a single day:
#doesn't work, however
collection_single_day = s2_merged_date_region.filterMetadata('system:index','contains',ymd_ee)
####
#Do some operations on the subset ImageCollection, resulting in some score
####
#Select date based on the maximum score.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just map over the list of dates.  The result will be a list of collections.

```
result = (ymd_ee
    .map(lambda date : s2_merged_date_region.filter(ee.Filter.eq('system:index', date)))
```

Also, there's no need to use `iterate` (you should never use iterate unless you need the value of the previous iteration in some kind of math), as you can simply map over the original collection. (also, system:index is a string, not a number).

```
ymd_ee = (s2_merged_date_region
    .map(lambda image : image.set('date', image.date().format("YYYYMMdd"))
    .distinct('date')
    .aggregate_array('date'))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. With that result in the first part, how would I go about, for instance, getting the geometry of the subsetted ImageCollection in `result`? For instance, `result.map(lambda img : img.geometry())` gives me `AttributeError: 'ComputedObject' object has no attribute 'geometry'`. Also, when running the ymd_ee in the second part, I get `AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'distinct'`

Comment: I misplaced a closing paren on the second part.  The .distinct is on the resulting collection (so there needs to be 3 closes on the map line).  For the first part, `result` is a list, so the stuff inside the list has no known type; you need to cast to ee.Image in the map.  But you can just take collection.geometry instead of collecting them yourself.

Comment: Wouldn't I have to cast to `ee.ImageCollection` instead? `result.map(lambda imgcol : ee.ImageCollection(imgcol).geometry())` gives me the result I want. And I appreciate the correction for the closing parenthesis; I had tried one at the very end but obviously that didn't work.

Comment: Yes, you'd convert to ImageCollection, using fromImages(), and then take the whole collection's geometry().  But if you have the result you want, you're probably fine as is.